# Consuming asp.net XML web service in android using ksoap2

Tags: android, asp.net, xml, web-services, ksoap

I am trying to consume an ASP.NET web service in Android with Ksoap2. Web service returns an XML response in browser like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  -<Students>
    -<student>
       <stdName>Maria</stdName>
        <stdRollNo>1</stdRollNo>
    -</student>
  -<student>
       <stdName>Anna</stdName>
        <stdRollNo>2</stdRollNo>
   -</student>
  -</Students>
```

On calling this service in Android with piece of code given below I get an exception:

```
Object response=null
try {
    httpTransport.call(soap_action,envelope);
    response=envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.v("response is ", response.toString());
} catch(Exception e) { 
    e.getMessage();
}
```

**Exception:**

```
response: "SoapFault" -faultcode:'soap:server' faultstrings: 'Server was not able to process request' object reference was not set to instance of an object"
```

I have made changes to that piece of code based on different suggestions given on Stackoverflow

```
SoapObject response=null
try{
    httpTransport.call(soap_action,envelope);
    response=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.v("response is ", response.toString());
} catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```

and

```
SoapObject response=null
try{
    httpTransport.call(soap_action,envelope);
    response=(SoapObject)envelope.getresponse();
    Log.v("response is ", response.toString());
} catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
}
```

But the exception then changes to:

```
java.lang.classCastexception
```

Any ideas as to what's happening?

Comment: I didnt work with ksoap2 but here is well documented and tested code for reading xml from web source http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1132/retrofit2/26230/reading-xml-form-url-with-retrofit-2#t=201612131143466235901

Answer (score 0):

You need to :
1/ Specify your method name (defined in your ASP.Net code) : webMethName.
2/ Use SoapPrimitive instead of SoapObject, it's where you'll get the web service respone.

Please edit your code block with the following :

```
    String resText = "";
    try {
        // Invoke web service
        httpTransport.call(soap_action + webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to resText variable                        
        resText = response.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Print error
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Assign error message to resText 
        resText = "Error occured";
    }
```

Comment: I have soap Method name appended in soap_action. and I tried your solution but same error

Comment: You need to share more of your code so that I see how are you invoking the code you pasted ?